# Getting an Incompatible types error when using List as a parameter

Tags: java

I have this method below which causes the error `error: incompatible types: UserSearchClause cannot be converted to List<UserSearchClause>` when trying to call `createInternalUserSearchClauses`.

The signature for `createInternalUserSearchClauses` clearly takes a `List<UserSearchClause>` as the param and `and` is clearly a `List<UserSearchClause>` so why am I getting this error?

```java
public UsersPage find(List<UserSearchClause> and) {
  List<UserSearchClause> internalAnd = createInternalUserSearchClauses(and);
}
```

```java
private UserSearchClause createInternalUserSearchClauses(List<UserSearchClause> userSearchClauses) {}
```

Comment: And what does the second method return...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of `createInternalUserSearchClauses` is not a list.